# Regex for both double precision value or empty string: ^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$

Tags: regex

For validation if a text is a double precision value, I use `^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$`. However, what regex should I use so that either an empty string or a double precision value would match?

Comment: What is a "double value"?

Comment: `-1.0e-123` is a valid `double` value, too - should it be matched?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 5):

You mean as in empty string?

You could use this:

```
^([0-9]\d*(.\d+)?|)$
```

Though to make it work as intended, you probably want:

```
^([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|)$
```

or

```
^(\d+(\.\d+)?|)$
```

Notice I put an or operator `|` there and since there's nothing after it, it will match an empty line.

Comment: You could also use an initial `\d*`. Then you would also match .1 as a value though, depends on your use case I guess. You would not require the final `|` in the regex.

Comment: @owlstead Indeed I could, but I decided against it since the OP seems to match at least one digit if there are any, with `[0-9]\d*`. But yes, with `\d*`, I wouldn't need the pipe, unless again things like `.1` are invalid!

Comment: Just a note, `(.\d+)?` was because the OP didn't put the regex in backticks so the `\.` got parsed as `.`

Comment: @doubleDown Oh, right, that would explain it. It didn't occur to me then ^^; Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
^\d*(?:\d\.\d+)?$
```

It will match strings like:

```
'123'
'123.4'
'0.3'
''
```

It will not allow strings start with a decimal point (e.g. `.3`); if you'd like allow that as well, use this:

```
^\d*(?:\.\d+)?$
```

If you'd also like allow strings that *end* with a decimal point (e.g. `3.`), use this:

```
^\d*(?:\.\d*)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this

```
^\d+([.]\d+)?$|^$
```